Proving that if $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{G}$, then $\bigcap \mathcal{G} \subseteq \bigcap \mathcal {F}$
I'm trying to prove the following statement from Dan Velleman's How to Prove It (p. 122):

Suppose $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are nonempty families of sets. Prove that if $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{G}$ then $\bigcap \mathcal{G} \subseteq \bigcap \mathcal{F}$.

My attempt
Suppose $x \in \bigcap \mathcal{G}$, i.e. $\forall A \in \mathcal{G} \space x \in A$. Also suppose $x \notin \bigcap \mathcal{F}$, i.e. $\exists B \in \mathcal{F} \space \text{s.t.} \space x \notin B$. Since $x \notin B$ but $\forall A \in \mathcal{G} \space x \in A $, it follows that $B \notin \mathcal{G}$. But this contradicts the assumption that $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{G}$, hence we conclude $x \in \bigcap \mathcal{F}$. Hence $\bigcap \mathcal{G} \subseteq \bigcap \mathcal{F}$. $\square$
Is this proof valid?
Streamlined version
Suppose $x \in \bigcap \mathcal{G}$, i.e. $\forall A \in \mathcal{G}\space x \in A$. Now, for an arbitrary $B \in \mathcal{F}$, $B \in \mathcal{G}$ since $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{G}$. This implies that $\forall B \in \mathcal{F} \space x \in B$ since $B$ was arbitrary, i.e. $x \in \bigcap \mathcal{F}$. Hence $\bigcap \mathcal{G} \subseteq \bigcap \mathcal{F}$. $\square$

It's correct, but unnecessarily long. Why don't you try a direct proof instead of a proof by contradiction?

How would you go about proving it directly? Trying $x \in \bigcap \mathcal{G}$ implies $x \in \bigcap \mathcal{F}$ because $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{G}$ would be affirming the consequent, no?

As mentioned, contradiction is not the best way to go here. If $x \in \bigcap \mathcal{G}$, what does this tell you about $x$? In what sets of the family $\mathcal{G}$ is $x$ contained?

$x \in \bigcap \mathcal{G}$ is equivalent to $\forall A \in \mathcal{G} \space x \in A$, so $x$ is contained in every set in $\mathcal{G}$?

"$x\in\cap \mathcal{G}$ implies $x\in\cap\mathcal{F}$ because $\mathcal{F}\subseteq \mathcal{G}$" is not "affirming the consequent" (that would be arguing that if $\cap\mathcal{G}\subseteq\cap\mathcal{F}$ then it must be the case that $\mathcal{F}\subseteq\mathcal{G}$). But it would just be stating the question again with confidence rather than actually proving it.

You already know that $x\in A$ for all $A\in \mathcal{G}$. Take any $B \in \mathcal{F}$, since $ \mathcal{F} \subseteq  \mathcal{G}$,  $B\in \mathcal{G}$. But then $x\in B$. And that was for any $B\in  \mathcal{F}$, so $x \in  \bigcap\mathcal{F}$.

Oh I see. Yes that makes sense, it is much cleaner and more straightforward than my proof.
